# Convert query from Postgresql to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, postgresql

I have a query in Postgresql

```
WITH RECURSIVE transitive_closure(a, b, distance, path_string)
AS
( SELECT a, b, 1 AS distance,
         a || '.' || b || '.' AS path_string
  FROM edges2

  UNION ALL

  SELECT tc.a, e.b, tc.distance + 1,
         tc.path_string || e.b || '.' AS path_string
  FROM edges2 AS e
  JOIN transitive_closure AS tc ON e.a = tc.b
 WHERE tc.path_string NOT LIKE '%' || e.b || '.%'
)
SELECT a, b, min(distance) AS dist FROM transitive_closure
WHERE a = 1 
GROUP BY a, b
ORDER BY a, dist, b;
```

I would like to convert it to SQL Server, is there any tool or someone can convert it for me?

Comment: Yes, that *tool* is called your **brain** - read up about how SQL Server does queries (the exact syntax), then convert your query.

Answer (score 0):

`recursive` is not a keyword in SQL Server.  You can remove it, a `with` is recursive by default in SQL Server.

In SQL Server you add strings like:

```
'Hello ' + 'World'
```

So replace the `||` with `+`.